# ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[256,1420,64] and type float

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I am having an issue with calculating my gradients where I am running out of memory, but I do not believe it has to do with actually not having enough memory. I have created my own layer, and I assume I am using an operation in there somewhere which may not be differentiable.

Here is my custom layer:

```
class MaskedDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  
  def __init__(self,
               units,
               max_num_features,
               activation=None,
               use_bias=True,
               kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
               bias_initializer='zeros',
               kernel_regularizer=None,
               bias_regularizer=None,
               activity_regularizer=None,
               kernel_constraint=None,
               bias_constraint=None,
               **kwargs):
    super(MaskedDense, self).__init__(
        activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer, **kwargs)

    self.units = int(units) if not isinstance(units, int) else units
    if self.units < 0:
      raise ValueError(f'Received an invalid value for `units`, expected '
                       f'a positive integer, got {units}.')
    self.max_num_features = max_num_features
    self.activation = tf.keras.activations.get(activation)
    self.use_bias = use_bias
    self.kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
    self.bias_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.get(bias_initializer)
    self.kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
    self.bias_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)
    self.kernel_constraint = tf.keras.constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
    self.bias_constraint = tf.keras.constraints.get(bias_constraint)

    self.input_spec = tf.keras.layers.InputSpec(min_ndim=2)
    self.supports_masking = True

    self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()

  def build(self, input_shape):
    dtype = tf.dtypes.as_dtype(self.dtype or tf.keras.backend.floatx())
    if not (dtype.is_floating or dtype.is_complex):
      raise TypeError('Unable to build `Dense` layer with non-floating point '
                      'dtype %s' % (dtype,))
    # input_shape = tf.TensorShape(input_shape)
    # last_dim = input_shape[-1]
    # if last_dim is None:
    #   raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
    #                    'should be defined. Found `None`.')
    self.input_spec = tf.keras.layers.InputSpec(min_ndim=2, axes={-1: self.max_num_features})
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(
        'kernel',
        shape=[self.max_num_features, self.units],
        initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
        regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
        constraint=self.kernel_constraint,
        dtype=self.dtype,
        trainable=True)
    if self.use_bias:
      self.bias = self.add_weight(
          'bias',
          shape=[self.units,],
          initializer=self.bias_initializer,
          regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
          constraint=self.bias_constraint,
          dtype=self.dtype,
          trainable=True)
    else:
      self.bias = None
    self.built = True

  def call(self, inputs, feature_mask=None):
    if feature_mask == None:
      kernel = self.kernel
    else:
      flattened_feature_mask = self.flatten(feature_mask)
      if self.units > 1:
        inputs = tf.expand_dims(inputs, axis=2)
        inputs = tf.repeat(inputs, self.units, axis=2)
        inputs = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(inputs, flattened_feature_mask)
        kernel = tf.expand_dims(self.kernel, axis = 0)
        kernel = tf.repeat(kernel, inputs.shape[0], axis=0)
        flattened_feature_mask = tf.expand_dims(flattened_feature_mask, axis=2)
        flattened_feature_mask = tf.repeat(flattened_feature_mask, self.units, axis=2)
        kernels = []
        for unit in range(self.units):
          kernels.append(
            tf.ragged.boolean_mask(
              tf.squeeze(kernel[:,:,unit]),
              tf.squeeze(flattened_feature_mask[:,:,unit])))
        kernels = tf.stack(kernels, axis = 2)
      else:
        inputs = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(inputs, flattened_feature_mask)
        kernel = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(tf.transpose(tf.repeat(self.kernel, feature_mask.shape[0], axis = -1)), flattened_feature_mask)
    if inputs.dtype.base_dtype != self._compute_dtype_object.base_dtype:
      inputs = tf.ops.math_ops.cast(inputs, dtype=self._compute_dtype_object)

    rank = inputs.shape.rank
    if rank == 2 or rank is None:
        outputs = tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(inputs, kernel), axis = 1), 1)
    else:
      outputs = tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(inputs, kernels), axis = 1), 1)
      outputs = tf.squeeze(outputs)
      # Reshape the output back to the original ndim of the input.
      # if not tf.executing_eagerly():
      #   shape = inputs.shape.as_list()
      #   output_shape = shape[:-1] + [kernel.shape[-1]]
      #   outputs.set_shape(output_shape)

    if self.use_bias:
      outputs = tf.nn.bias_add(outputs, self.bias)

    if self.activation is not None:
      outputs = self.activation(outputs)
    return outputs
```

It's purpose is to take a tensor of continuous inputs which have a large amount of missing values and a boolean mask tensor of the same shape with True and False values denoting which features should be masked and which should not. The point here is to mask the missing values so as to not have to drop all observations which having missing values, which would be most of the data set, or have to attempt to impute a value.

It does this by creating a weight kernel with shape equal to the maximum number of possible features, and takes the dot product between the masked inputs and the masked kernel, so that the output of the layer ignores any missing values. I assume this is causing issues with calculation of the gradient.

Does anybody know how I might debug this? I am not too familiar with inspecting tensorflow gradients.

Here is the entire error:

```
ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/masked_dense_27/strided_slice_56/StridedSliceGrad' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 972, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 712, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 504, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 493, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 400, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 724, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 383, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 528, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2880, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2935, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3134, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3337, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3397, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18196\1844441298.py", line 14, in <cell line: 14>
      model.fit(
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "c:\Users\JJ\Documents\Git\cig_dbbuilding\.venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18196\572172987.py", line 134, in train_step
      gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_variables)
Node: 'gradient_tape/masked_dense_27/strided_slice_56/StridedSliceGrad'
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[256,1420,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node gradient_tape/masked_dense_27/strided_slice_56/StridedSliceGrad}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_58824686]
```

Here is my train step where the error occurs:

```
def train_step(self, inputs):
        """Custom train step using the `compute_loss` method."""

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss = self.compute_loss(inputs, training=True)

            # Handle regularization losses as well.
            regularization_loss = sum(self.losses)

            total_loss = loss + regularization_loss

        gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))

        metrics = {metric.name: metric.result() for metric in self.metrics}
        # metrics["loss"] = loss
        # # metrics["regularization_loss"] = regularization_loss
        metrics["total_loss"] = total_loss

        return metrics
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: And why would gradient calculation issues lead to an OOM error? An OOM error occurs when your system goes OOM. Try reducing batch size and/or model size and see if it persists. Also check whether other processes are hogging significant memory.

Comment: I will try that. It just seems very strange. I have ran this model without the custom layer and it has plenty of memory leftover. I would assume this is only happening due to a bug with my custom layer using significantly more memory than necessary.